# nodejs socket write ordering

Tags: node.js, sockets

When writing a nodejs proxy server I noticed that data may come into my proxy many times before the data is written to the other socket end. each time my data comes in, i call socket.write(); ...

However I am unsure if the order of the data being transmitted is guaranteed by nodejs to be the same as the order i scheduled the writes due to the asynchronous nature of the sending.

Does anyone know the behavior of nodejs in this situation?

If the order is not guaranteed, then i will have to buffer the data until i recieve the data successfully sent callback.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Node.js is single threaded and can only ever do one thing at a time. It has a queue of callbacks that get processed in order.
some more information can be found here: http://howtonode.org/understanding-process-next-tick.

As long as you are calling socket.write when you receive data then it will arrive in order. If you think about it, if it didn't do this then node would not be usable as a webserver. For example, a simple node express site might use fs.readfile to read a file from disc asynchronously and serve it back to the browser using socket.write. If the order was not guaranteed, that file might not be returned correctly.

From the node 0.8.14 documentation:
http://nodemanual.org/latest/nodejs_ref_guide/net.html#net.Socket.write

> Returns true if the entire data was flushed successfully to the kernel
>   buffer. Returns false if all or part of the data was queued in user
>   memory. 'drain' is emitted when the buffer is again free.

and

> net.Socket has the property that socket.write() always works. This is
>   to help users get up and running quickly. The computer can't always
>   keep up with the amount of data that is written to a socket—the
>   network connection simply might be too slow. Node.js will internally
>   queue up the data written to a socket and send it out over the wire
>   whenever it's possible. (Internally, it's polling on the socket's file
>   descriptor for being writable.)

Comment: I know it makes sense that it would do it in order, but I've heard other people say its not guaranteed. I guess all that matters is whether or not socket.write uses a queue for storing buffered writes before they happen. Maybe someone knows?

Comment: Is is possible that other people were referring to other stream implementations? Not socket specifically? Have you got a link or reference?

Comment: Also, TCP is going to ensure that the packets get delivered in order.  Once the packets hit the network, they may not arrive in order (technically), but TCP will ensure that the client code receives them in the correct order.